# How can I fix "bash: screen: command not found" in shell file

Tags: bash, shell

Whenever I run this code I always get the error "bash: screen: command not found"
The code's supposed to run spigot.jar, while also doing a few other things (not my code)

I really don't know what to try, but I do think I might have to be using linux (which would be a pain in the ass figuring I only have one computer)

```sh
screen -S powercraft/PRISON -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "stop\r"`" ;
screen -S root/PRISON -p 0 -X stuff "`printf "stop\r"`" ;
sleep 10 ;
pkill -f PRISON ;
cp -r /home/ALL/update/plugins-1.8/* plugins ;
cp -r auto/* plugins ;
sleep 1 ;
rm -rf auto/* ;
screen -d -m -S PRISON java -server -Xmx6G -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=30 -XX:+UseBiasedLocking -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+AggressiveOpts -jar spigot.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I can see the command `pkill`. `pkill` is a Linux command not available on Windows. You don't have to install linux on your pc. You can use a virtual machine or you can install linux subsystem on windows 10. Instructions on the later can be found [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-linux-subsystem-for-windows10/)